# Using CURL to download from batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl

I am trying to download the maya devkit using CURL from a batch file:

```
call curl https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/autodesk-adn-transfer/ADN+Extranet/M%%26E/Maya/devkit+2018/Maya2018-DEVKIT_Windows.zip --output tmp.zip
```

However this gives me an empty output file. Weirdly, if i run the exact same command in `cmd` (minus the extra percentage sign), it works perfectly.

Is there any symbols that I may need to escape for this particular command to work?

Comment: The call command essentially is screwing up the escaping of the percent symbols. You don't need the CALL command anyways.

Comment: Remove `call` and put the URL in between `""`... (note that with `call` you'd need to use `%%%%` to get a literal `%`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)" -L "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/autodesk-adn-transfer/ADN+Extranet/M%26E/Maya/devkit+2018/Maya2018-DEVKIT_Windows.zip" -o tmp.zip
```

Or put into `.bat`/`.cmd` batch file, by this:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)" -L "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/autodesk-adn-transfer/ADN+Extranet/M%%26E/Maya/devkit+2018/Maya2018-DEVKIT_Windows.zip" -o tmp.zip
```

It's adviced to add a Useragent by `-A` switch, also you need to enclose the url with double quotes.
Sometimes you'll also need `-L` and `-e RefererURL` to download file.

Usually the `call` is unnecessary, if you want it to download in a separate thread, you can use `start`. Use `call` when you need to call a sub procedure/function and pass parameters, and since it's another layer of batch call, you also need to double the `%` again, since it's escaped twice.
Which means, this will work in a batch file:

```
call curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)" -L "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/autodesk-adn-transfer/ADN+Extranet/M%%%%26E/Maya/devkit+2018/Maya2018-DEVKIT_Windows.zip" -o tmp.zip
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I tried adding the `call` command before curl and it didn't work, so I guess that is probably part of the reason though i have no idea why...

Comment: @JohnTan Sure thing:)  Usually the `call` is unnecessary, if you want it to download in a separate thread, you can use `start`. Use `call` when you need to call a sub procedure and pass parameters, and since it's another layer of batch call, you also need to double the `%` again, since it's `escaped` twice (4 `%`s instead 2).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation!